# Creating nested list items dynamically

Tags: javascript

Getting the JSON data like below. I want to make a nested list (ul-li) dynamically using js.

```js
[
    {
        "code": "A00",
        "depth": "0",
        "row": [
            {
                "code": "A001",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar eltor"
            },
            {
                "code": "A009",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Cholera, unspecified"
            }
        ],
        "disease": "Cholera",
        "title": "a"
    },
    {
        "code": "A01",
        "depth": "0",
        "row": [
          {
              "code": "A0103",
              "depth": "1",
              "disease": "Typhoid pneumonia"
          }
        ],
        "disease": "Typhoid and paratyphoid fevers",
        "title": "a"
    },
    {
        "code": "A010",
        "depth": "0",
        "row": [
            {
                "code": "A0102",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Typhoid fever with heart involvement"
            },
            {
                "code": "A0103",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Typhoid pneumonia"
            },
            {
                "code": "A0104",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Typhoid arthritis"
            },
            {
                "code": "A014",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Paratyphoid fever, unspecified"
            }
        ],
        "disease": "Typhoid fever",
        "title": "b"
    },
    {
        "code": "A02",
        "depth": "0",
        "row": [
            {
                "code": "A020",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Salmonella enteritis"
            },
            {
                "code": "A021",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Salmonella sepsis"
            }
        ],
        "disease": "Other salmonella infections",
        "title": "b"
    },
    {
        "code": "A022",
        "depth": "0",
        "row": [
            {
                "code": "A0221",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Salmonella meningitis"
            },
            {
                "code": "A0224",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Salmonella osteomyelitis"
            },
            {
                "code": "A0225",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Salmonella pyelonephritis"
            },
            {
                "code": "A0229",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Salmonella with other localized infection"
            }
        ],
        "disease": "Localized salmonella infections",
        "title": "c"
    }
]
```

json being shortened and title being changed for readability. I want to achieve something like

```
a
  Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar eltor
  Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar eltor
  Typhoid pneumonia
b
  Typhoid fever with heart involvement
  ..
```

title with same value all the row data should come in the same list title. No title should be repeated. Instead the object with same title, it's row(key) data should come in list as shown just above.

Below is what I have tried till yet

```js
for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
  let list = document.createElement('li');
  let ulist = document.createElement('ul');
  let span = document.createElement('span');
  span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(json[i].title));
  for (let j = 0; j < json[i].row.length; j++) {
    let nestedList = document.createElement('li');
    span.classList.add('caret');
    list.appendChild(span);
    ulist.classList.add('nested');
    list.appendChild(ulist);
    nestedList.appendChild(document.createTextNode(json[i].row[j].desease));
    ulist.appendChild(nestedList);
  }
  let mainUl = document.getElementById('someId');
  mainUl.appendChild(list)
}
```

and this is what I am getting (sample result) with no success in getting the desired result

```
a
  xyz
a
  abc
b
  ...
b
  ...
```

Please let me know if require more information or I am not clear to you.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of one way to do it.

```js
var json = [
    {
        "code": "A00",
        "depth": "0",
        "row": [
            {
                "code": "A001",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar eltor"
            },
            {
                "code": "A009",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Cholera, unspecified"
            }
        ],
        "disease": "Cholera",
        "title": "a"
    },
    {
        "code": "A01",
        "depth": "0",
        "row": [
          {
              "code": "A0103",
              "depth": "1",
              "disease": "Typhoid pneumonia"
          }
        ],
        "disease": "Typhoid and paratyphoid fevers",
        "title": "a"
    },
    {
        "code": "A010",
        "depth": "0",
        "row": [
            {
                "code": "A0102",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Typhoid fever with heart involvement"
            },
            {
                "code": "A0103",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Typhoid pneumonia"
            },
            {
                "code": "A0104",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Typhoid arthritis"
            },
            {
                "code": "A014",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Paratyphoid fever, unspecified"
            }
        ],
        "disease": "Typhoid fever",
        "title": "b"
    },
    {
        "code": "A02",
        "depth": "0",
        "row": [
            {
                "code": "A020",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Salmonella enteritis"
            },
            {
                "code": "A021",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Salmonella sepsis"
            }
        ],
        "disease": "Other salmonella infections",
        "title": "b"
    },
    {
        "code": "A022",
        "depth": "0",
        "row": [
            {
                "code": "A0221",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Salmonella meningitis"
            },
            {
                "code": "A0224",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Salmonella osteomyelitis"
            },
            {
                "code": "A0225",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Salmonella pyelonephritis"
            },
            {
                "code": "A0229",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Salmonella with other localized infection"
            }
        ],
        "disease": "Localized salmonella infections",
        "title": "c"
    }
];

function buildList(json) {
 var list = {}
  //Loop over the json object and build our new object
  for(var k in json){
    //Grab the title
   var group = json[k].title;
    //Check to see if our new title has this key
    if(!(group in list)){
      //If not, initialize it as an array
      list[group] = [];
    } 
    //Add all the row.disease entries to the array
    for(var x in json[k].row){
      list[group].push(json[k].row[x].disease);
    }
  }
  
  //Build the html
  var html = '';
  //Itterate over our new list
  for(var x in list) {
    //Add the title key
    html += '<li>' + x;
    //Check to make sure the array isn't empty
    if(list[x] != []){
      //Add the nested ul
      html += '<ul>';
      //ITterate over the items for this key and add li
      for(var item in list[x]) {
        html += '<li>' + list[x][item] + '</li>';
      };
      //Close the ul
      html += '</ul>';
    }
    //close the li
    html += '</li>';
  }
  $('#main').html(html);
}

buildList(json);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="main"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive build over the data, it will support any depth.

```js
const data = [
    {
        "code": "A00",
        "depth": "0",
        "row": [
            {
                "code": "A001",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar eltor"
            },
            {
                "code": "A009",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Cholera, unspecified"
            }
        ],
        "disease": "Cholera",
        "title": "a"
    },
    {
        "code": "A01",
        "depth": "0",
        "row": [
          {
              "code": "A0103",
              "depth": "1",
              "disease": "Typhoid pneumonia"
          }
        ],
        "disease": "Typhoid and paratyphoid fevers",
        "title": "a"
    },
    {
        "code": "A010",
        "depth": "0",
        "row": [
            {
                "code": "A0102",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Typhoid fever with heart involvement"
            },
            {
                "code": "A0103",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Typhoid pneumonia"
            },
            {
                "code": "A0104",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Typhoid arthritis"
            },
            {
                "code": "A014",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Paratyphoid fever, unspecified"
            }
        ],
        "disease": "Typhoid fever",
        "title": "b"
    },
    {
        "code": "A02",
        "depth": "0",
        "row": [
            {
                "code": "A020",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Salmonella enteritis"
            },
            {
                "code": "A021",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Salmonella sepsis"
            }
        ],
        "disease": "Other salmonella infections",
        "title": "b"
    },
    {
        "code": "A022",
        "depth": "0",
        "row": [
            {
                "code": "A0221",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Salmonella meningitis"
            },
            {
                "code": "A0224",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Salmonella osteomyelitis"
            },
            {
                "code": "A0225",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Salmonella pyelonephritis"
            },
            {
                "code": "A0229",
                "depth": "1",
                "disease": "Salmonella with other localized infection"
            }
        ],
        "disease": "Localized salmonella infections",
        "title": "c"
    }
];

const buildLI = (data) => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerHTML = `code: ${data.code} - ${data.disease}`;
  li.appendChild(span);
  if(data.row) li.appendChild(buildUL(data.row));
  return li;
};

const buildUL = (data) => {
  const ul = document.createElement('ul');
  data.forEach(d => {
    ul.appendChild(buildLI(d));    
  });
  return ul;
};

document.querySelector('div').appendChild(buildUL(data));
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: This is, IMHO, the best of the answers.  Using `createElement` and `appendChild`, and wrapping those in functions with mutual recursion, is an elegant way to go about this.  The one thing I might suggest improving is to cut out the repetition of the data from the question (and replace it with a comment saying the data is as specified in the question -- assuming you haven't actually changed it -- at a cursory glance, it looks the same).  (That way we can directly see the core code right away.)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to the existing answer: If you want a bit more readability in your code you could just create a string and append it to your container via `innerHTML`. More straightforward and easier to maintain for simple tasks.

```
let html = '';

items.forEach(item => {
    html += `
    <ul>
        <li>${item.code}</li>
            <li>
                <ul>`;

    item.row.forEach(row => {
        html += `<li>${row.disease}</li>`;
    });

    html += `
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>`;
});

console.log(html);
document.querySelector('#my-wrapper').innerHTML = html;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to group your top-level by title, you will need to make sure to only create a new top-level list once per title.

You may find it easier to create a an object that keeps track of the top-level list elements.

The following code (modified from above) creates an object that keeps track of the `span`, `ulist`, and `list` elements, using title as the key. This prevents duplicate top-level lists.

```js
const json = [{
    "code": "A00",
    "depth": "0",
    "row": [{
        "code": "A001",
        "depth": "1",
        "disease": "Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar eltor"
      },
      {
        "code": "A009",
        "depth": "1",
        "disease": "Cholera, unspecified"
      }
    ],
    "disease": "Cholera",
    "title": "a"
  },
  {
    "code": "A01",
    "depth": "0",
    "row": [{
      "code": "A0103",
      "depth": "1",
      "disease": "Typhoid pneumonia"
    }],
    "disease": "Typhoid and paratyphoid fevers",
    "title": "a"
  },
  {
    "code": "A010",
    "depth": "0",
    "row": [{
        "code": "A0102",
        "depth": "1",
        "disease": "Typhoid fever with heart involvement"
      },
      {
        "code": "A0103",
        "depth": "1",
        "disease": "Typhoid pneumonia"
      },
      {
        "code": "A0104",
        "depth": "1",
        "disease": "Typhoid arthritis"
      },
      {
        "code": "A014",
        "depth": "1",
        "disease": "Paratyphoid fever, unspecified"
      }
    ],
    "disease": "Typhoid fever",
    "title": "b"
  },
  {
    "code": "A02",
    "depth": "0",
    "row": [{
        "code": "A020",
        "depth": "1",
        "disease": "Salmonella enteritis"
      },
      {
        "code": "A021",
        "depth": "1",
        "disease": "Salmonella sepsis"
      }
    ],
    "disease": "Other salmonella infections",
    "title": "b"
  },
  {
    "code": "A022",
    "depth": "0",
    "row": [{
        "code": "A0221",
        "depth": "1",
        "disease": "Salmonella meningitis"
      },
      {
        "code": "A0224",
        "depth": "1",
        "disease": "Salmonella osteomyelitis"
      },
      {
        "code": "A0225",
        "depth": "1",
        "disease": "Salmonella pyelonephritis"
      },
      {
        "code": "A0229",
        "depth": "1",
        "disease": "Salmonella with other localized infection"
      }
    ],
    "disease": "Localized salmonella infections",
    "title": "c"
  }
];

const topLevel = {};
const titleSpan = (title) => {
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(title));
  return span;
};
const li = () => document.createElement('li');
const ul = () => document.createElement('ui')
for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i+=1) {
  const title = json[i].title;
  topLevel[title] = topLevel[title] !== undefined
  ? topLevel[title]
  : { 
    list: li(),
    span: titleSpan(title),
    ulist: ul(),
   };
  const {span, ulist, list} = topLevel[title];
  for (let j = 0; j < json[i].row.length; j+=1) {
    let nestedList = document.createElement('li');
    span.classList.add('caret');
    list.appendChild(span);
    ulist.classList.add('nested');
    list.appendChild(ulist);
    nestedList.appendChild(document.createTextNode(json[i].row[j].disease));
    ulist.appendChild(nestedList);
  }
  let mainUl = document.getElementById('someId');
  mainUl.appendChild(list)
}
```

```html
<div id="someId"></div>
```